# Simple Google Map not working in JsFiddle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsfiddle

Can somebody please guide me how to create a basic Google Map in JsFiddle?

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
function initialize(){
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:15,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });
marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Link to JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/doublezed2/dvoav0ng/20/

Thanks,
Zubair

Comment: I have already added this url in external resources but it is not working.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js

thanks for your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is using its own event listener interface, while `JSFiddle` is trying to execute your code within a `jQuery` `onLoad` event handler

To make it work, you need to execute the map code directly in the `<head>`:

https://jsfiddle.net/dvoav0ng/24/

This is done by setting the option `No wrap - in <head>`